# Distribution of the index of sample maximum

Tags: r

I am pulling a sample of 10 independent binomial distributed random variables Xi and then finding the index of the largest of them. I thought each would be equally likely to be the maximum however the histogram shows a distinct pattern, heres the [histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOYTE.jpg)

I used the following code in R:

```
n=10^5

Which_maximum = function(x){
  sample1 = rbinom(10,5,0.5)
  return(which.max(sample1))
}
repeat1 = sapply(1:n,Which_maximum)
hist(repeat1)
```

This seems really odd, thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: This doesn't relaly appear to be an actual coding problem?  What is your question exactly?

Comment: For continuous distribution, yes, they are equally likely, but `rbinom` is a discrete distribution. So there are ties. `which.max` returns only the first index.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `which.max` determines the location of the **first**  maximum of a numeric vector.
For example, try this code:

```
set.seed(23456)
x <- rbinom(10,5,0.5)
print(x)
[1] 2 3 3 4 3 2 3 4 4 3
which.max(x)
[1] 4
```

In vector `x` there are 3 tied maximum values but `which.max` gives you only the position of the first. Of course, this issue modifies the distribution of the index of the largest value.

Alternatively, you can use the command `which.is.max` of the `nnet` package, which *"Find the maximum position in a vector, breaking ties at random"*:

```
library(nnet)
n <- 10^5
which_maximum <- function(x) {
  sample1 <- rbinom(10,5,0.5)
  return(which.is.max(sample1))
}
repeat1 <- sapply(1:n,which_maximum)
barplot(table(repeat1))
```

[image]